# ./configure--with-boost no such file or directory

Tags: linux, boost, compiler-construction, configure, construction

When I used ./configure the terminal returned:

> checking for Boost headers version >= 1.41.0... no configure: error:
>   cannot find Boost headers version >= 1.41.0

So i used the command  "./configure-with-boost=/usr/include" also but it only returns

> No such file or directory

I have the latest version of Boost headers extracted to /usr/include

Comment: I am trying to configure LHAPDF-6.1.4

Comment: Did you mean `configure --with-boost=/usr/include`? Note the space before --.

Comment: yes sorry my fault. I have added the space but now it just says **checking for Boost headers version >= 1.41.0... no
configure: error: cannot find Boost headers version >= 1.41.0**

Comment: Can you confirm that the file `/usr/include/boost/version.h` exists?

Answer (score 0):

`--with-boost=...` is a command line options that must be separated with at least one whitespace from the name of the executable and the rest of arguments, i.e.

```
./configure --with-boost=/usr/include
```

Comment: I think you are only suppose to point to the install prefix, not the include directory within the install prefix, e.g. `./configure --with-boost=/usr` or more likely something like `./configure --with-boost=/opt/whatever`

Answer (score -1):

I have solved the problem it was just some developmental libraries were missing and it was giving the boost error instead to cover for this.

Comment: What software was missing? Please include all packages that have to be installed in order to solve the issue,