# Ubuntu command line: running ./configure results in error 'cannot find Boost headers'

Tags: boost, ubuntu-14.04, configure, git-clone

I'm trying to install the latest version of dlvhex. I downloaded it from [here](http://www.kr.tuwien.ac.at/research/systems/dlvhex/downloads.html) (I'm using the developmental version because it's the only one that's recent enough). I've been following the instructions, and `git clone` worked and `./bootstrap.sh` worked, but then when I try to run `./configure` I get the following error:

```
checking for Boost headers version >= 1.55.0... no
configure: error: cannot find Boost headers version >= 1.55.0
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

*More information if needed*
Boost version 1.64 is in my Home folder.
I'm running Ubuntu14.04
It's ridiculously long so I won't post it now, but let me know if you need the full output from when I run `./configure` and I'll add it to my question.

*Note*
This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573618/configure-with-boost-no-such-file-or-directory) one but that question never got a satisfactory answer so I thought I'd better ask again.

**Update**
I've done a bit more troubleshooting and have found some information that may be relevant. In configure.log I found the following two sections:

Section one

```
configure:17740: checking for Boost headers version >= 1.55.0
configure:17811: g++ -c -W -Wall    -O3    conftest.cpp >&5
conftest.cpp:63:3: error: #error Boost headers version < 105500
 # error Boost headers version < 105500
```

And section two

```
| #include <boost/version.hpp>
| #if !defined BOOST_VERSION
| # error BOOST_VERSION is not defined
| #elif BOOST_VERSION < 105500
| # error Boost headers version < 105500
| #endif
```

This seems to imply that the boost header version.hpp is being checked and BOOST_VERSION being identified as less than 1.55.

Here is version.hpp (with the comments taken out so it's more readable):

```
#ifndef BOOST_VERSION_HPP
#define BOOST_VERSION_HPP
#define BOOST_VERSION 106400
#define BOOST_LIB_VERSION "1_64"
#endif
```

Based on this information I think that configure must be checking a boost folder, seeing that it's version is too low, and giving up without checking any other boost folders - I must have two conflicting versions of boost installed. However, I can find no secondary boost folders on my computer.

Can anyone help me either verify whether or not it really is a conflicting boost version causing this problem, figure out how to remove the conflicting version, or suggest any alternative theories on what may be causing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer; since I had manually saved the boost folder to my home directory, it was not in the 'expected' location, so I simply needed to use `./configure --with-boost=/path/to/boost/folder`.
It's a little embarrassing that it took me so long to figure that out but I'm glad I found the answer in the end.